# Niveles de usuario

Tags: diseño

Estoy desarrollando un sistema para una empresa y como saben, hay niveles de usuarios y no todos pueden tener acceso a toda la funcionalidad del sistema.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: que conviene a la hora del aislamiento, tener un menú para cada tipo de usuario, donde se le restringe el acceso a la información que no puede acceder. O bien tener subprogramas diferentes para cada tipo de usuario.

Pregunto por el hecho de no tener un programa tan pesado para todos los tipo de usuarios, siendo que no van a acceder a toda la funcionalidad.

---

Exacto, es justamente como lo tenía desarrollado. Pero la cabeza de la empresa me está pidiendo que cambie y que tenga proyectos diferentes. Tengo mi ventana Login y de acuerdo al tipo de usuario dispara para el menú correspondiente. En fin, voy a ver como lo hago entrar en razón. Gracias por colaborar!

Comment: Coloca fotos para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo primordial es el menu del login, por medio del nivel de usuario que ingrese puedes o no otorgar permisos para mostrar cierta opciones, puede ser mostrando una vista diferente dependiendo del nivel. Si en tu caso utilizas un solo menu para la verificación del usuario y es eso lo que lo incomoda puedes probar implementando un menu que tenga una pestaña para el usuario y otro para el administrador.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo importante es el **LOGIN** y que cada tipo de usuario tenga acceso a ciertas funciones. Creo que seria buena idea tener un **menú** para cada usuario después del **login**.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que deberías autenticarte por medio del login y después si el login es correcto , tendrías que autorizar a cada usuario por medio de permisos que estén guardados en base de datos y que tú menú lo armes en base a esos permisos, ya que esto te da la flexibilidad de no tener que estar manteniendo n menús por n usuarios, puedes checar spring security o apache shiro